# Trying to start rails console causes a stack too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Any time I try to start rails console, I get a stack level too deep error, and have no idea how to solve the issue.

Stacktrace here: https://gist.github.com/3519364

When I run rails console, what exactly happens? What parts of my application does that command touch, and in what way?

EDIT 1:

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
config.cache_classes     = false
config.whiny_nils        = true
config.consider_all_requests_local = true 
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "localhost",
  :port => 1025,
  :authentication => :none
}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
```

Nothing is fixed by removing excon unfortunately. I even went so far as to quadruple the stack size for `rails c` and still the problem persists. What makes this even more frustrating is that there are four other developers working on the same project and NONE of them are having the same problem. This leads me to believe it's not actually an issue in the codebase or gems.

Comment: Can you post the first 10 lines of your environment.rb? and see if your console works if you uninstall the excon gem

Comment: @KyleC My edit includes the response

Comment: In your initializers/mime_types.rb, comment out line 102

Comment: My mime_types.rb is only 4 lines, all of them commented out.

Comment: checkout this link, https://github.com/jacott/rails-latex/issues/19,  this could be the bug warning: already initialized constant PDF

Comment: Thank you so much! A simple `bundle update` solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar issue,  github.com/jacott/rails-latex/issues/19 , a bundle update should solve your bug.